# Failed to install a project to a real device

Tags: swift, swift3

Someone who solved this problem by emulating on an iPhone.
It is a project that a library was embedded and well I already gave it a lot of laps and all the Build Setting configurations, from the signature of the build functions are correctly I do not understand what may be happening I have xcode 12.0.1 I will thank you very much for a feetback,
este es mi error:

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: _$s8DropDownAAC9DirectionO6bottomyA2DmFWC
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E7CFCF6-F3E3-422F-8EF9-BD721F6D0ADB/proyectodemo.app/Frameworks/FrameworkDemo.framework/FrameworkDemo
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E7CFCF6-F3E3-422F-8EF9-BD721F6D0ADB/proyectodemo.app/Frameworks/DropDown.framework/DropDown
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E7CFCF6-F3E3-422F-8EF9-BD721F6D0ADB/proyectodemo.app/Frameworks/FrameworkDemo.framework/FrameworkDemo
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
(lldb)
```

Comment: Have you try latest version of Xcode?